# Fonts is getting blur when google map iframe is loaded

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I've notice something strange in one of my page.
The fonts in the page is getting very blur after google maps is loaded.
The page:
http://aranrd.wpengine.com/contact/
You can see that at the moment google maps is loaded, the fonts inside it's section, inside the grey area, getting blur.
This is a page template I've build for the contact page.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">

    <div id="contact-page">

        <h1><?php _e( 'CONTACT', 'aran-rd' ); ?></h1>

        <div id="primary" class="content-area contact-inner">


            <div class="row top-row">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id=2 title=false description=false ajax=false]'); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <!-- google maps iframe -->
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/embed?mid=zWesdBo33x1E.kHaxSgqiUyNY" width="640" height="280"></iframe>

                    <div class="row inner-row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <div class="location-details">

                                <?php _e( '43 Haeshel Street,<br/>Caesarea Buisness Park<br/>P.O.B 3067', 'aran-rd'); ?>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <div class="contact-details">

                                <?php _e( 'Tel: 972-4-623-9000,<br/>Fax: 972-4-627-3260<br/>E-mail: info@aran-rd.com', 'aran-rd'); ?>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div><!--.inner-row-->

                </div>

            </div>


        </div><!--#primary-->

    </div><!--#contact-page-->

</div><!--.container-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the margin-bottom from `top-row` solve the problem, no idea why.